# WCF IIS service file streaming The remote server returned an unexpected response: (400) Bad Request.

Tags: .net, wcf, iis

I am trying file uploading through wcf service hosted in iis 8 
i am using visual studio 2010.
I am getting below error
how I can provide a stream which will write file on server

The remote server returned an unexpected response: (400) Bad Request.

web config

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="false" targetFramework="4.0" />
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
  <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding  name="BasicHttpBinding_IService"
              transferMode="Streamed"
              messageEncoding="Mtom"
              maxReceivedMessageSize="10067108864"
             />
    </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior>
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
<serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

app config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <system.serviceModel>
        <bindings>
        <basicHttpBinding>
            <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IService"
                     maxReceivedMessageSize="10067108864"
                     transferMode="Streamed"/>
        </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
        <endpoint address="http://localhost/FileService/Service.svc"
            binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IService"
            contract="ServiceReference1.IService" name="BasicHttpBinding_IService" />
    </client>
</system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

code

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IService
{
[OperationContract]
void UploadFile(System.IO.Stream fstream);
}
```

Comment: Maybe show your service contract? Maybe even the start of your service?

Comment: looks like I got the problem , it's in binding, I will post the answer soon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the problem its in my config files

I need to change my web config as below

```
<system.serviceModel>
<bindings>
  <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding maxReceivedMessageSize="999999999" transferMode="Streamed" messageEncoding="Mtom"/>
  </basicHttpBinding>  
</bindings>
```

and app config as below

```
 <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
        <basicHttpBinding>
            <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IFileService" maxReceivedMessageSize="10485760"  transferMode="Streamed" messageEncoding="Mtom"/>
        </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
```